# R 3D plot axis tick labels

Tags: r, graphics, 3d, cloud, lattice

I'm plotting a 3D histogram in R using the method from figure 6.15 [here](http://learnr.wordpress.com/2009/07/20/ggplot2-version-of-figures-in-lattice-multivariate-data-visualization-with-r-part-6/).

I've set scale = list(arrow=F), so that I have tick marks instead of arrows on each axis.

The plot looks fine, but I want to change the axis tick labels. My x-axis goes from 1-26, my y from 1-24, and my Z from 0-8E-6. Ideally I'd like a single label at each of the discrete x and y values, and then at some reasonable interval on the z axis.

I've tried using the scale option 'tick.number', but it seems to only take one number, or use the first in a list, so if I set it to 26 I get excess tick marks on the y axis, and the z axis looks like rubbish.

I see there is an 'at' and 'labels' options in scales, much like for 2D plots, but I can't seem to get it to work. The docs indicate it should be a list of vectors with locations and labels for each panel, so I tried:

`at = list(c(1:26), c(1:24), c(2*10^-6, 4*10^-6, 8*10^-6))`

but it complains:

```
(list) object cannot be coerces to type 'double'
```

I presume if I figure out how to use 'at' then 'label' should become clear.

EDIT:

Here is sample code:

```
library(latticeExtra)
Cg = 1:25
Cr = 1:25
freqs = rnorm(25, .5, .1)
cloud(freqs~Cg*Cr, xlim=c(27,-1), ylim=c(25,-1), panel.3d.cloud=panel.3dbars, par.settings=list(box.3d = list(col="transparent")), col.facet="grey",  scales=list(arrows=F))
```

My data has different lengths X and Y axes, and not just the diagonal is filled, but it shows the axis problem.

Comment: Please add a reproducible example. The page you link to contains several plots, both for lattice and ggplot2. Avoid ambiguity and add an example dataset.

Comment: I noted that it was figure 6.15 on the linked page.

Answer (score 1):

From the docs of `cloud` (`lattice`):

> ‘at’ gives the vector of
>             cutpoints where the colors change

So it needs to be a vector, not a list of vectors. The error you are getting is caused by a failure to transform your list of vectors to numeric:

```
at = list(c(1:26), c(1:24), c(2*10^-6, 4*10^-6, 8*10^-6))
> as.numeric(at)
Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

The `at` parameter describes where the colors change, similar to `levelplot`. So it only needs to be one vector.

Comment: From the docs of cloud(lattice):
`Scales: a list describing the scales. As with other high level functions ... It can also contain components with the special names x, y and z, which can be **similar lists** with axis-specific values overriding the ones specified in scales.`

If i give it one long numeric vector, then it uses the same places to make marks on all 3 axes. One vector gives it no indication where one axis ends and another begins. If I do:
`at = c(1:26,1:26,4*10^-6,4*10^-6)`
For example, it works, but I get far too many ticks on the x and y axes, and none on the Z.

Comment: There are different uses of the 'at' argument in different contexts. See my example below.

Answer (score 1):

Those result needs further work, but it does satisfy your request and shows you what is meant by passing the arguments to 'scales' as a list:

```
cloud(freqs~Cg*Cr, xlim=c(27,-1), ylim=c(25,-1),zlim=c(0,1), # needed to add zlim
   panel.3d.cloud=panel.3dbars, par.settings=list(box.3d = list(col="transparent")), 
   col.facet="grey",  
   scales=list(arrows=F, x=list(at = c(1:26), lab=c(1:26)) , 
                         y=list(at= c(1:24),  lab=c(1:24)),
                  z= list(rot=20,   # to prevent over-riding the tick marks
                          at= c(.2,.4,.8) ,      # data spans larger range
                          lab=c("2*10^-6  ", "4*10^-6  ", "8*10^-6  ") )
       )       )
```

[image]

The range of z is simply not what you offered with those small values, so you need to accept that reality. If you want to relabel the proportions, then I have shown you how to do it.